# Data is not POSTing through Retrofit API 2.1.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to post data in a bean to database but I am not able to post my data. I had written web-service for that but getting error in android app

```
 public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mEditTextName;
    private EditText mEditTextEmail;
    private EditText mEditTextPassword;
    private EditText mEditTextAddress;

    private Button mButtonRegisterUser;

    private TextView mResponseTextView;

    APIService mAPIService;

    private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mEditTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        mEditTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
        mEditTextAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAddress);
        mEditTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

        mButtonRegisterUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegisterUser);

        mResponseTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResponse);

        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

        mButtonRegisterUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String lName = mEditTextName.getText().toString();
                String lEmail = mEditTextEmail.getText().toString();
                String lAddress = mEditTextAddress.getText().toString();
                String lPassword = mEditTextPassword.getText().toString();

                sendPost(lName, lAddress, lEmail, lPassword);
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendPost(String lName, String lAddress, String lEmail, String lPassword) {

        mAPIService.registerPost(lName, lAddress, lEmail, lPassword).enqueue(new Callback<POST>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<POST> call, Response<POST> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    showResponse(response.body().toString());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<POST> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: Unable to post data");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showResponse(String response) {

        if (mResponseTextView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mResponseTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        mResponseTextView.setText(response);
    }

}
```

My activity code. I had provided permission for internet access

```
 public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit sRetrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseURL) {
        if (sRetrofit == null) {
            sRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return sRetrofit;
    }
}
```

APIUtils describing base  url

```
public class ApiUtils {

private ApiUtils() {

}

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/services/webapi/registerService/";

    public static APIService getAPIService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }
}
```

API Service for defining methods

```
    public interface APIService {

    @POST("register")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<POST> registerPost(@Field("name") String name,
                            @Field("email") String email,
                            @Field("password") String password,
                            @Field("address") String address);
}
```

Comment: any error logs?

Answer (score 0):

if your response is

```
{
    "message": "Successful"
}
```

then create a class

```
public class RegisterResponse {
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

In you interface class make the following change

```
public interface APIService {

    @POST("register")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<RegisterResponse> registerPost(@Field("name") String name,
                            @Field("email") String email,
                            @Field("password") String password,
                            @Field("address") String address);
}
```

When calling the function

```
mAPIService.registerPost(lName, lAddress, lEmail, lPassword).enqueue(new Callback<RegisterResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Response<RegisterResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    showResponse(response.body().getMessage());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegisterResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: Unable to post data");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Comment: No I don't have any JSON pair of "message". I am passing response back in String